# Why netcat -k doesn't work and doesn't keep alive the connection?

Tags: netcat, nmap

The -k parameter doesn't work neither with nc (netcat) nor with ncat nor with nmap.

Comment: Try nc -kvl <port>

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install netcat-openbsd with this command:

```
sudo apt install netcat-openbsd
```

Before this you have to remove any different version of netcat.